# Installing Bootstrap Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently learning ruby on rails and 
trying to install bootstrap gem

but this message shows up when I do rails server.

```
An @import loop has been found:  
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

I followed every step correctly but this shows up

Comment: can you post the contents of application.css.scss ?

Comment: and the version of the bootstrap gem that you use ?

Comment: Hello, Yes! Here is my github account: https://github.com/younggue/pinteresting..........I added gem 'bootstrap-sass' on the gem file and on css file I created new bootstrap page and added @import 'bootstrap';

Comment: I dont see the bootstrap-sass in the gemfile.lock or the import syntax. I assume you have not pushed them yet. this might be what you are facing. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/69 hope this helps. if it does not, give me more details to debug

Comment: hi, i uploaded the lastest code on github. I really would be appreciated if someone takes a look at it

Comment: I just fixed it, thank you

Comment: You should add your own answer how you fixed it @user2998413 so that if anyone else has the issue in the future they can resolve it using your question & answer!